# Match anything between quotes except commas

Tags: java, regex, match

I have this regular expression: `(?<=")(?:\\.|[^"\\])*(?=")`

It matches every character inside quotes and excludes quotes themselves.

When I try it with a string like this:

```
"one","two","three"
```

it also matches the commas, so the result of the match is the following:

```
one
,
two
,
three
```

Is there a way to modify the regex to make it exclude those commas? That is, so that the output is:

```
one
two
three
```

#### I need to exclude those quotes in regex as well as not to include commas in the match result.

#### Here is my big regex:

`((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.\d\d\d\d)|(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])|"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"`

The first part matches date: dd.mm.yyyy

#### ((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).\d\d\d\d)

The second part matches time: hh:mm:ss

#### (([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])

And the last one is supposed to match all the characters between the quotes:

#### "((?:\.|[^"\])*)"

But the last part on the regex doesn't work in a way that it doesn't exclude the quotes. And moreover, for some reason it removes all the spaces in strings that are enclosed with quotes.

#### The input is the text file with strings like that:

```
"AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","23.02.2015","07:45:00","23.02.2015","09:20:00","False","True","23.02.2015","07:40:00","2","Common","AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","Common"
```

#### The expected output is the array of values in quotes (of course, without commas and quotes themselves). The reason why I use such big regexes for matching dates and time is that they shouldn't be matched if they're wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your regex not to match commas, you need to remove the lookarounds and use capturing groups to fetch the contents between double quotes. Because lookarounds are assertions which won't match any character. So in this `"one","two","three"` input at first your regex matches `one` then it matches the following  `,`, since comma was also present inside the double quotes.

```
"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"
```

This regex forces to match each block of double quoted string.

Java code would be,

```
String value = "\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"((?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*)\"").matcher(value);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
one
two
three
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vT7eK2/1)

Comment: This one does seem to work better than mine, looks good! I didn't even know you could link directly from the website, to be honest.

Comment: But what if the regex you provided is a part of another big regex? Would it work?

Comment: yep, it would. If not, then post the bigger regex here.

Comment: I've added my big regex. Unfortunately, it doesn't work right

Comment: could you provide the input along with the expected output?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I've added it to the question

Comment: @DenisYakovenko why you check for dates and hours? just https://regex101.com/r/vT7eK2/2 would be enough. Create an empty list and add the contents for group index 1 to the list . Am i correct?

Comment: `The reason why I use such big regexes for matching dates and time is that they shouldn't be matched if they're wrong.` could you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Well, if it is like 61:65:98 - the time is wrong, obviously, and if it is like 32.13.2015 - the date is also wrong.

Comment: but last you're trying to match all the strings within double quotes. So the last part of your regex matches also the wrong parts.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help:) I guess I'll just have to rethink my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this ?

```
"(.*?)"
```

for the string "one", "two" , "three", "four" : Matches will be :

```
one
two
three
four
```

See here : [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oJ3fQ6/1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: it won't deal with the escaped quotes.

Comment: Yes, the capturing group just keep things INTO commas

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are attempting is to match every group of alphanumeric characters between quotes. If that is the case, you can use the following regex:

```
(?<=")([a-zA-Z0-9]*)*(?=")
```

I usually use a site like https://regex101.com/ to test my regexes. Makes it very easy to see why things are matched! The reason you were matching your commas as well was that those were technically still characters between apostrophes.

Comment: This doesn't match alphanumeric characters. It matches capital or lowercase letters. Alphanumeric needs a range like `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `[a-zA-Z\d]`

Comment: Silly me, forgot to add that part. Thanks!